# change image attribute

Tags: jquery

i have image tag on dom but i can't change attribute of that

```
$('#stuff').prop("disabled", true);
```

or

```
$('#stuff').attr("disabled", true);
$('#stuff').click(function(){ ... });
```

html:

```
<img src='images/system_help.png' id='stuff' width='18px'/>
```

after use prop or attr i can click on the tag

Comment: `img` element doesn't have disabled property.

Comment: Could you restate your question for clarity please? It is difficult to know what you are asking.

Comment: What would a disabled image do differently?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

Only form elements have a disabled attribute.  Instead, try unbinding your event ala:

```
$('#stuff').unbind();
```

Comment: thanks,how to bind now?`$('#ckekeKala').bind();` not work for me code

Comment: rebind by assigning the event handler again:  
$('#stuff').click(function(){ ... });

Answer (score 1):

Only form elements can be disabled.  `img` is not a form element.
What are you trying to achieve by disabling the `img`?  If you are trying to remove the click handler then

```
$('#stuff').unbind('click');
```

Will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There's no attribute `disabled` for `img`.

I think you need `one`.

`$('#stuff').one(function(){ ... });`